# 500 Internal Server Error - No Error Log

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, internal-server-error

I had a function that worked just fine. Then i uploaded it to the live server and it gave me a 500 internal server error. After googling people said its an error you get when something(but they arent sure what) is messed up with the server. Not very helpful. others said check your error log. I have no idea how to get to it.

Function that causes the error ===============================

```
 private function get_workstation () {
  //================ I tried deleting all but this and that got rid of the error== //
    if ($this->input->post('search')) {
        $search = $this->input->post('search');
        $where = 'ad_name ="'.$search.'" AND';
        $this->data['search'] = $search;
    } else {
        $where = '';
    }
    // ================================================================= //
    // Pagination Code //
    $numOfRows = $this->db->query('
        SELECT distinct sys_name 
        FROM v_rollout_sysuser 
        WHERE scope_ID = '. $this->session->userdata('scopeId') .'
    ');

    if ($this->input->get('page')) {
        $pageNum = $this->input->get('page');
    } else {
        $pageNum = 1;
    }

    $limit = ($pageNum - 1 ) * 50;
    $numRows = $numOfRows->num_rows();
    $totalPages = ceil($numRows / 50);

    $this->data['pageNum'] = $pageNum;
    $this->data['prevPage'] = $pageNum - 1;
    $this->data['nextPage'] = $pageNum + 1;
    $this->data['totalPages'] = $totalPages;

    // End of Pagination Code //

    $query = $this->db->query('
        SELECT * 
        FROM v_rollout_sysuser
        WHERE '.$where.' scope_ID = '. $this->session->userdata('scopeId') .'
        GROUP BY sys_name 
        LIMIT '.$limit.',50');

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $data['i'] = $i;
        $data['ro_ID'] = $row->ro_ID;
        $data['sys_name'] = $row->sys_name;
        $data['EAM_Model'] = $row->EAM_Model;           
        $data['EAM_User'] = $row->ad_account;
        $data['ad_DispName'] = $row->ad_DispName;
        $data['search'] = $this->input->post('search');

        $systems[] = $data;
    }

    if(isset($systems)) {
        $this->data['systems'] = $systems;
    } else {
        $this->data['systems'] = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: If your function works fine locally but doesn't on a server, it'll be because the two machines are configured differently - it's worth checking to make sure that your local machine and the server are using the same versions of PHP, mySQL, and that both have the same configuration.

Comment: Do you have access to server error logs? Those will contain a more detailed version of the message

Comment: Sadly i'm not the one that runs the live server but i will talk to him about it.

Comment: @Pekka i might but i dont know how to access them

Comment: @DylanButh - track down your error logs.  Talk to your sysadmin.  Sysadmins love it when people want to fix their own problems.

Comment: I will but he thinks this is a code problem. I was just trying to fix the code. but i guess thats not really the problem. I kinda regret the question now. haha

Comment: Your sysadmin has access to the error logs and should be able to tell you the exact reason. At least it should be a more meaningful message than just "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Here's what you can do to troubleshoot:

Upload the function but remove all the code in it (empty function).  If that works, add a few lines of code starting from the top and find the faulty line.  Are you sure both servers have the same database structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out there was a problem with the database. Sorry to those who spent time trying to help. The guy running the database found the problem. Thank for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to load any page of your CodeIgniter website or just a particular one?

The following steps might help you to debug:

in your main .htaccess file add these lines:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

in your main index.php section "Application environment", set the 'development' environment:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

and you can also enable CodeIgniter error logging in your config/config.php file, section 'Error Logging Threshold'

If any of these don't make any progress, contact your server admin :)

Comment: It is this and a handful of other pages that dont work. The majority of them do though

Answer (score 0):

it could be the double `->`s in `$this->input->post`, try splitting it into separate sections, e.g.

```
$a = $this->input;
if ($a->post('search')) {
```

In my experience, some configurations do not like doubles like `$this->input->post`, especially older versions and some IIS configs

Comment: ah maybe not that then :) Have you tried progressing though the code? e.g. after each part, stop the script with `die("here")` or something similar, until you get to the point where the fatal error gets there first, and you will find the line that causes the error? works for me most of the time!  either way, hope you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd do following to debug if iwere you:

1. Set php error reporting to 8191, display_errors to 1 in php.ini
2. Use isset in each relevant condition.
3. Check db connection manually.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$search = $this->input->post('search');
if ($search) {
    $where = 'ad_name ="'.$search.'" AND';
    $this->data['search'] = $search;
} else {
    $where = '';
}
```

Comment: That's what i originally had but i changed it when i was messing around with it